# Getting error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:"

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am using selenium webdriver for the testing application. i am using using Marionettedriver for the browser. however when I run the code it gives the error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:" I have check the system path also no issue in the same.
so please suggest how to solve the error.

Also getting error " error: Found argument '--webdriver-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    geckodriver.exe [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]".
I am not able to understand for what issue this error is appears. So please let me know how to solve this

I have used the jar file for selenium server and selenium standalone server in the project. still same error shows. Also as mentioned above it shows the error of " error: Found argument '--webdriver-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    geckodriver.exe [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]".

Comment: Heads up! When you post a question about Firefox Marionette, please use the [tag:firefox-marionette] tag. **DO NOT** use the [tag:marionette] tag. Okay? I've retagged two questions posted by you yesterday. I'm getting tired of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your webdriver tests, you need to "obtain" browser from selenium server/grid. `Connection refused` message means there is no listening server on a host/port you provided.